# How to kill tensorboard with Tensorflow2 (jupyter, Win)

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

sorry for the noob question, but how do I kill the Tensorflow PID?

It says:

`Reusing TensorBoard on port 6006 (pid 5128), started 4 days, 18:03:12 ago. (Use '!kill 5128' to kill it.)`

But I can not find any PID 5128 in the windows taks manager. Using '!kill 5128' within jupyter the error returns that comand kill cannot be found. Using it in the Windows cmd or conda cmd does not work either.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Windows cmd type `tasklist | more` It will display all the process running in the system and find **tensorboard.exe** [image]

You can kill the process using the process ID

```
taskkill /F /PID 20036
```

you can kill the process by its name

```
taskkill /IM "tensorboard.exe" /F
```

Comment: killing the process is not enough though, see answer above

Answer (score 23):

If you clear the contents of `AppData/Local/Temp/.tensorboard-info`, and delete your logs, you should be able to have a fresh start

Answer (score 1):

I am using docker image. There was a case where the same error occurred even though the tensorboard process was already killed. In that case, if you are using the jupyterlab docker image, just delete the files in `/tmp/tensorboard-info` path.

Answer (score 1):

for me combination of both,

1. running this code on cmd prompt `taskkill /IM "tensorboard.exe" /F`
2. deleting this file AppData/Local/Temp/.tensorboard-info
   worked